# Using regular expressions to remove everything in a specific block of characters

Tags: regex

I have searched and found numerous examples, but i dont understand them.

What im trying to do is delete a LOT of blocks of text in a certain text file.

For example :

```
`active_targeted_decision={
            decision="ROM_romanisation_campaign_subject"
            target=1                ignore=no
            days=0
            state=available
        }`
```

The file is full of text like this, but the difference is that "target-1" goes up to a very large number. So theres target=1, target=2, target=3, etc.

What i want to do is search for and remove everything that matches the following block of text :

```
`active_targeted_decision={
            decision="ROM_romanisation_campaign_subject"
            (everything inside this block of code)
        }`
```

To clarify, that means it should also replace "active_targeted_decision={" and "}" with blank space, as well as everything inbetween.

The examples ive found via searching say to use "<.*?>" but i dont see how it helps my situation....can anyone help?

Comment: Are there additional `}` inside the block?

Comment: @Armali: Nope..

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, since there are no additional ending braces inside the block. Indeed the ungreedy `.*?` helps, because using it avoids matching from the start of the first block all the way to the end of the last block.

[`/active_targeted_decision={\s*decision="ROM_romanisation_campaign_subject".*?}/gs`](http://regexr.com/5pqm7)

Important is also the *dotall* flag `s` to enable matching over multiple lines.

Comment: That didnt get any results unfortunately. Someone else helped me with this and his seems to have worked : 

    `active_targeted_decision={
.*decision="ROM_romanisation_campaign_subject"
.*target=[0-9]*.*ignore=no
.*days=0
.*state=available
    .*\}`

Comment: Surely that won't match `(everything inside this block of code)`.

Comment: It seems to have when  I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use

```
active_targeted_decision\s*=\s*\{
[^{}]*
decision\s*=\s*"ROM_romanisation_campaign_subject"
[^{}]*
\}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YHneJD/1) (mind the modifiers, especially `x` for verbose).